# Ajax simple messaging application

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am developing a simple messenging system where the clients will be able to create conversation for each project and communicate with a project manager.

What I have acomplished so far is send / delete the message via jQuery and Ajax.

```
<ul class="messages" id="messages">
            <?php
                foreach ($replies as $reply): // replies stores all messages for this current conversation between two users
            ?>
            <li class="message" id="message"><?php echo $reply->content; ?><a href="<?php echo $reply->id; ?>" id="delete">delete</a></li>
            <?php
                endforeach;
            ?>
        </ul>
```

However this works one way. The client or the project manager is able to see their messages but will only be able to see the replies when they refresh the page.

Is there anyway to query the database for messages and update the list with the replies ??

```
jQuery(function(){


            $("#messages").on('click', '#delete', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var id = $(this).attr('href');
                $.post( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>messages/delete", { type:'single', id:id } )
                  .done(function( data ) {
                    });
                $(this).closest('.message').remove();
            });

        $('#send').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var reply = $('#reply').val();
            var project_id = 44;
            if(reply==""){
                return false;

            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>messages/send",
                data:{ msg:reply, project_id:project_id, user_id:2, admin_id:1},
                success: function (response) {

                    if(response){

                        $(".messages").append('<li class="message">'+reply+'<a href="'+response+'" id="delete">delete</a></li>');
                        $('#reply').val('');
                    }else{

                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can poll the server every minute or so to get updates, you can do long polling, or you can do websockets.  Then you need to write the code that takes the data you get back and loops through it placing it in the proper place on the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to do some more complex stuff where you open and listen on a socket, you will need to poll for the results. You can create a javascript function that will send an ajax request to the server on a timer and send back the messages. Be careful though, you could end up making a lot of requests if you have a lot of users.

Here is the gist of a fun way to do it using a recursive function with setTimeout and a $.Deferred object:

```
function poll_timer(data, def, frequency){

    def.notify(data,def);

    $ajax.('getmessage.php').done(
    function(results){ 
       setTimeout(
                function(){
                    poll_timer(data,def);
               }, frequency);
       }
   );
}
```

then you can implement it like this (polling every three seconds):

```
var def = $.Deferred();

def.progress(function(data,def){
    $('#target').html(data.message);
});

poll_timer(null, def, 3000)
```